# ansible playbook syntax error

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible playbook throwing a syntax error, however everything looks correct. 
What can be the issue on the role?

**ERROR**:

```
The error appears to have been in '/home/Desktop/playbooks/xx.yml': line 6, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.


The offending line appears to be:

roles:
    - role: chronos_task
      ^ here
```

**CODE**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - role: chronos_task
      no_log: true
      chronos_url: 'http://{{ chronos_host }}:{{ chronos_port }}'
      chronos_tasks:
        - type: iso8601
```

Comment: for the record. several YAML validators determined that this chunk was valid YAML.

Comment: yes i even tried executing in aws environment, i still not sure where the syntax error might be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can be the issue on the role?

The issue **might be** that the `chronos_task` role is not present in roles' path.

This is the exact error message you get in such a situation.

Comment: If this is actually the problem, then `ansible-lint` would be helpful here as it throws errors on missing roles.